# How to use pep8 module using Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder, pep8

Is there any way to use pep8 module to check whether the code is compliant with pep8 specifications in Spyder (Anaconda)?
I also tried to run the command `pep8 --show-source --show-pep8 testsuite/E40.py` given at https://pypi.org/project/pep8/ in the command prompt, but it gives syntax error (`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`).

Comment: "...but it gives syntax error" which we should all discover to help you. Please read here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and complete you question with at least some more information like the returned syntax error, a pip freeze list of packages in your environment, whether or not you're using a virtualenv.

Comment: @TonyMoutaux 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' This is what i get. And I am not using any virtual environment. Also you are very rude.

Comment: Did you try to run that command in a Python repl? It's a command for your shell, not for Python. @TonyMoutaux wasn't rude at all, they're asking for more information; I doubt that's all the traceback you got, give a [mcve] that lets other people replicate the issue.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks. It is working in the shell. I was trying it in Python

Answer (score 23, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You can activate pep8 support in Spyder 3 by going to

`Tools > Preferences > Editor > Code Introspection/Analysis`

and activating the option called

`Real-time code style analysis`

This will show pep8 warnings directly in our Editor, so you don't need to run `pep8` from the command line to see them.

Comment: You should look at @Marius Sterling Answer for the newer edition.

Answer (score 22):

Amendment to [Carlos response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51467284/12667377): In Spyder 4 this option has been moved to

`Tools > Preferences > Completion and linting > Code style`

where you have to accept

`Enable code style linting`

FYI, in this new version specific errors or warnings can be selected to be shown or ignored!